# Make SafariViewController tint completely black

Tags: ios, sfsafariviewcontroller

I am trying to make SafariViewController black (iOS 10, iOS 11).

I have the code:

```
let svc = SFSafariViewController(url: url!, entersReaderIfAvailable: false)
svc.preferredBarTintColor = .black
svc.preferredControlTintColor = .white
```

However, this makes it gray (vs black). I believe the reason is that it's translucent.

Is there a way to make it completely black?